# Function with PA symbols and minimum function are recursive:

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

I'm asked to prove the following:

a) A function $f$ defined by the terms of $PA$ (Peano Arithmetic), that is, a function defined by $+$, $\cdot$ and $S(x)$ over any set (probably the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?) is a recursive function.

b) And if $f(x,y)$ is a recursive function then a function $g(f(x,y))$ defined by $g(f(x,y))= min \{ z \, | \, f(x,y) \hbox{ exists for each } y \leq z \land f(x,y)=0 \}$ and $g(f(x,y))$ undefined otherwise, then $g(f(x,y))$ is a recursive function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What definition of a recursive function are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by '$f(x,y)$ exists'?

Comment: @Couchy A function is recursively enumerable if it is recursively enumerable as a set

Comment: @Couchy  The definition I have of a recursively enumerable set is: $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ if it is definible by a formula $\sum _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{  } $. A formula is  $\sum _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{  } $ if it is of the form $\exists x\psi $ with $x$ variable and $\psi$ bounded formula.